# Why is Chokidar using so much memory?

Tags: node.js, watch, fs

I am evaluating Chokidar (1.4.3) after reading promising comments about it.
If I understood correctly it should use native code to detect file changes.

The test I am running is on a Windows 8.1 x64 system.

When I run a simple test on a folder containing lots of files and subfolders, it seems like every file and folder is scanned during initialization, taking about 40% of CPU and consuming a lot of memory. This seems more like default node fs.watch behavior and not the "native OS" way.

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');

var dataWatcher = chokidar.watch('c:/data/tryout', {
        persistent: true,
        ignoreInitial: true,
        usePolling: false
    });

dataWatcher.on('all', function(event, path){
        console.log(event, path);
    });
```

Any ideas on how to get the native (Windows) OS behavior as you would have using SystemFileWatcher in C# ?

```
C:\data\tryout\chokidar>npm list chokidar
tryout@0.0.0 C:\data\tryout
└── chokidar@1.4.3
```

Comment: I never used that library but by looking at the documentation it looks like only OSX is optimized, not the other OS. The intro contains *"Be advised that chokidar will initiate watchers recursively for everything within scope of the paths that have been specified, so be judicious about not wasting system resources by watching much more than needed."*

Comment: @DenysSéguret I read somewhere that it was using native routines though I cannot find out where I have read it anymore. What I did find is that even fs.watch (used by Chokidar internally) should user native Windows routines...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718275/node-js-monitoring-for-when-a-file-is-created#answer-23718389